# Switchcase feito para REACTFLUX não está pegando o case certo

Tags: javascript, react

Por que não está recebendo a action.type? acaba saindo em default.

O log está dizendo "editando" que é o caso default em vez de criar um novo artigo.

**The code**

```
  handleActions(action) {
    switch (action) {
    case action.type === ActionTypes.CREATE_ARTICLE:
        this.setState.article.id = Counter.increment();
        this.setState.article.title = action.title;
        this.setState.article.content = action.content;
        console.log("adicionado")
        break;
    case action.type === ActionTypes.DELETE_ARTICLE:
        console.log("deletando")
        break;
    default:
        console.log("editando")
        break;
}
  }
```

**Print do log:**

[image: Here the log print]

Na imagem acima cria o objeto porém o log sai no default "editando".

[Código todo](https://github.com/danilosilvadev/juridico-blog)

Comment: O que dá `console.log(action, ActionTypes.CREATE_ARTICLE);`?

Comment: Dá a imagem do print que postei na pergunta. Esse objeto do tipo CREATE_ARTICLE.

Comment: E `console.log(ActionTypes.CREATE_ARTICLE);`?

Comment: mesma coisa. O lance é q em vez de cair no case 1 que é o do CREATE_ARTICLE está caindo no default. Esse é o problema.

Comment: @Sergio eu mudei um pouco o código e o erro mudou. Agora aparece isso:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'article' of undefined`

É sobre essa linha:`this.setState.article.id = Counter.increment();`

E o construtor que tem esse id é esse:

`constructor() {
        super();
        this.article = {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            article: ""
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Bom parece que flux não tem state e essas paradas de components. Falei com o grupo oficial do team react e a melhor opção pra mim é fazer uma gambiarra ou ir pro redux. Só tenho uma coisa a dizer:"Adeus flux!"